# AWS EC2 can't execute user-data script

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

I'm pretty new to AWS and EC2 but I want to run instances with a user script after it's booted from another instance. I have installed ec2 tools and ran the command as it's explained in various examples like here http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/ec2-userdata and Eric Hammond's tutorials. however when I actually use the command:
"ec2-run-instances --key my-key --user-data-file myscript my-ami"
it only runs the new instance but doesn't execute the script
myscript contains:
 #!/bin/bash 
echo "hello" > ~/output.txt

I'm running ubuntu server 12.04 AMIs. the target AMIs are duplicates of the initiating instance.

if I run curl http:// 169.254.169.254/latest/user-data the imported script is there.

Comment: Make sure your sample script is two lines. It won't execute as you have described it in a single line.

Comment: Make sure you are looking for the output in /root as the user data script is run as root.

Comment: Make sure you can execute the sample user data script on an official Ubuntu AMI before you try the same command on your own AMI.

Comment: The script actually DID run and the output was in /root. Thanks Mr. H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[copying answer from comments to answer entry]*

Make sure you are looking for the output in `/root` as the user data script is run as the `root` user on first boot.

Other things to consider for others having similar issues:

- Make sure your sample script is two lines. It won't execute as you have described it in a single line.
- Make sure you can execute the sample user data script on an official Ubuntu AMI before you try the same command on your own AMI